# How to get keys from an array in typescript

Tags: typescript, angular7

```
value =   {
     5c03dbc3d8e3e3435f875a46: "1", 
     5c03dc0fd8e3e3435f875a48: "2", 
     5c03dc30d8e3e3435f875a49: "3", 
     5c03dc5fd8e3e3435f875a4a: "4"
     }
```

I have an array like this. I want to get key from this array, so that I can use it to get values associated with those keys. This all is for typescript.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have an array, you have an object literal. If it were an array, you would use brackets `[ ]` instead of curly braces `{ }`. Also, array keys are always integer numbers from 0 to `length -1`.

To answer your question. If you want all keys from your `value` object, you can use `Object.keys(value)`.

Comment: Whether correct practice or not, arrays in typescript can absolutely use non-integers as keys.